# how to check values in one column are all identical by a second grouping variable?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am using r to analyse some data that is in long format. I have one column that is a grouping variable which contains participant IDs and another variable that contains their sex.

e.g.

```
ID SEX
1   M
1   M
2   F
2   F
2   M
```

I would like to check whether there are any IDs which do not have sex coded consistently e.g. ID=2 above. Is there a way to do this? I have been playing around with dplyr and the group_by function, but I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In terms of output, I would probably like a vector of all unique ID values that have non-identical values in the SEX column.

Comment: I think I would like a vector of all unique ID values that have non-identical values in the SEX column. Does that make sense?

Comment: so you mean you want to identify those ids for which the coding is not (M-1 & F-2) .like the last row ?

Comment: No, I would like to identify values of ID like ID==2 (rows 3 to 5), where the values of SEX are not consistent (e.g. they do not all = M OR they do not all = F).

Comment: This would give you the unique ID's : `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(SEX) >1) %>%
  distinct(ID)
`. I am sure there are multiple other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R soultion using `ave()` -

```
df[ave(df$SEX, df$ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1, ]

  ID SEX
3  2   F
4  2   F
5  2   M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
require(plyr)

df <- data.frame(c(1,1,2,2,2), c('M','M','F','F','M'))
names(df) <- c('ID','SEX')

df2 <- ddply(df,.(ID), mutate, count = length(unique(SEX)))
unique(df2[df2$count > 1,][1])
```

Result:

```
ID
2
```